# Una promesa dentro de useEffect regresa undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy haciendo uso de hoooks para hacer el llamado a un API, pero al momento de setearlo a la función de mi useState me regresa udefined. El api regresa un objeto que se llama photos y este objeto contiene un array con la información que necesito. Este es mi código:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { BASE_URL } from '../utils/constants';


const Photos = () => {

    
    const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(BASE_URL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then( data => setPhotos(data.photos))
    }, [])

    
    return (
        <div className='section'>
            <h1>componente</h1>

            
            
        </div>
    )
}

export { Photos }
```

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, pero creo que debes colocar tu setPhotos dentro de tu array del segundo argumento del useEffect, algo así: `useEffect(() => {...}, [setPhotos])`, así le dices al effect que vuelva a cambiar los valores de esas variables si algo cambia en el effect

Comment: So colocas un `console.log(photos)` antes del `return`,  al iniciar la `App` deberías ver dos logs, uno con `undefined` y el otro con los datos a asignados, a menos que algo haya salido mal en la llamada `async fetch`, ¿Puedes confirmar si es así?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces un fetch deberías esperarlo con await porque es una promesa. Un ejemplo sería utilizando una función async y dentro el await de fetch:

```
export const Photos = () => {

    const [ photos, setPhotos ] = useState([]);

    const apiFetch = async (url: string) => {
        return await fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        apiFetch(BASE_URL)
            .then(data => setPhotos(data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, []);

    console.log(photos);

    return (
        <div className='section'>
            <h1>componente</h1>
        </div>
    );
};
```

un saludo!